# How to extract individual images of words from a picture?

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I am trying to extract images of words from a picture that mostly has sentences in different type fonts. For example, consider this scenario:
[image]

Now I would want to extract individual images of words Clinton, Street and so on like this:
 
[image]

I tried applying the binary dilation but the distance between the white and black area was almost negligible to crop out the words. However, there was a little success when I first cropped out the blank area in the original image and then re-do the binary dilation on the cropped image with a lower F1 value.

What should be the best and high-accuracy approach to separate out images of the words from this picture?

Ps: I am following this blog [post](http://www.danvk.org/2015/01/07/finding-blocks-of-text-in-an-image-using-python-opencv-and-numpy.html) to help me get the task done.

Thank you
 
Fennec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dilatation, I get this :
[image: result]

Is this not satisfactory for you because of the fact that lines may be too close by and merged together with dilatation (like it sort of happens for the last two lines) ?

Other stuff to try, from the top of my head :

-clustering.

-low level method where you count number of pixels in each line to find out where the lines are, then count the pixels in each column to figure out where the words are in each line.

Comment: @Solitus Thank you very much for this information. I think I will be able to use it and attain my final results.